# .Net read file VS Perl read file implementation

Tags: .net, wcf, perl, file-upload

I am sending a .zip file to a WCF service via basicHTTPBinding (SOAP 1.1) as a bytes array.

Basically, a file is read from the disc and sent to a server in a text envelope object.

In .net, I read the file from the disc in the following manner:

```
...

var bytes = ReadGridLibFile(path + fileName);

....
private static byte[] ReadGridLibFile(string fileName)
        {
            byte[] bytes;
            int numBytesToRead;
            using (FileStream fsSource = new FileInfo(fileName).OpenRead())
            {
                // Read the source file into a byte array.
                bytes = new byte[fsSource.Length];
                numBytesToRead = (int)fsSource.Length;
                int numBytesRead = 0;
                while (numBytesToRead > 0)
                {
                    // Read may return anything from 0 to numBytesToRead.
                    int n = fsSource.Read(bytes, numBytesRead, numBytesToRead);

                    // Break when the end of the file is reached.
                    if (n == 0)
                        break;

                    numBytesRead += n;
                    numBytesToRead -= n;
                }
                numBytesToRead = bytes.Length;
            }
            return bytes;
        }
```

When such bytes array is sent to WCF service, it is being written to the disc on a server side and becomes an openable .zip achive.

I need to implement a perl client for the same uploading functionality.

In perl, I read bytes like this:

```
while (read(FILE, $buf, 60 * 57)) {
$bytes .= $buf;
}
close(FILE);
$bytes = encode_base64( $bytes );
```

When I put $bytes as data in an envelope object and manually send it via HTTP::Request, on the server, I get an array of bytes, but when saved to the disc,it is a bad (broken) zip archive. What is the problem with the way I am reading and sending bytes array in perl?

Comment: Did you use `binmode(FILE)`?

Comment: And you could reduce that loop to `my $buf; { local $/; $buf = <FILE>; }`

Comment: @ikegami, thanks for the tip. I didn't, but on the server, I have arrived at the same problem, even if I switch to binmode.

Comment: Binmode actually appeared to be the solution, along with `encode_base64( $bytes, '' );` to make sure encoding isn't adding line endings. So you can post binfile as a response and I will mark it as a correct answer. Thanks!